# Facebook JS API: how do I read the read_stream data?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook JavaScript API and have gone over their documatation and cannot find the answer to the following question.

After a user has granted your application specific permissions (in this case read_stream), how do you obtain that particular data? To be more specific I am using the following as part of my login process:

```javascript
function login(){
    alert("[fbCommon]" + ' > login');
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            //console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            alert("[fbCommon]" + ' > login > ' + 'Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                //console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                alert("[fbCommon]" + ' > login > ' + 'Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
            });
        } else {
            alert("[fbCommon]" + ' > login > ' + 'User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            //console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
        }
    }, {scope: 'read_stream'});
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is their stream/feed data, change the

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {...})
```

to

```
FB.api('/me/feed', function(response) {...})
```

You can use the trusty [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me/feed) to check this